# Apple FairPlay Key Server Module Implementation

Tags: ios, drm, fairplay

Has anybody managed to implement this part? Apple has released some reference code along with the FairPlay SDK (preview), but there are quite some missing bits. Is there any guides / tutorials, which would help / guide the implementation?

Comment: Have you managed to get it work? I am surprised that there are only few entries about Apple FairPlay and KSM(Key Server Module) implementation. I would be glad if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: same question - were you able to manage to implement it?

Answer (score 5):

The most troublesome part of the reference is that it's missing the private key which they say to just put in some array. PROBLEM: the key is in a pem file and has a textual represntation.
After a little bit of testing I was able to overcome this.
I took the relevant .pem file which starts with the line "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and then the base64 encoded key and finishes with "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" so I just took all the data (including opening and closing lines) and converted it to a bytes represntation.
I used the following python code
`file = open("dev_private_key.pem", "r")
a = file.read()
b = new bytearray(a)
for ch in b:
  sys.stdout.write(str(ch)+",")`

Then I took this output and just pasted it in the required line in SKDServerUtils.c so it looks something like this
static const UInt8 pKeyPem[] = {45,45,45,45,45....}

Recompiled it all and it works well for me.

Hope this helps people in the future since I couldn't find any better documentation on this specific part.

Comment: Can you elaborate, how were you able to manage the implementation. In SDK provided by apple, I can see some .h and .c files. Where to host these files? and how to manage client calling the key server module?

Comment: I run it with a linux system, I created my own makefile and compiled it as a shared library, then you can use whatever framework to load that library.
The method you should be calling is "SKDServerGenCKC" declared in "SKDServer.h" note that there are a few places in the code you have to edit (they are clearly marked)